# Do limit ordinal always have a preceding limit ordinal

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

I am trying to prove that a non zero limit ordinal $\gamma$ always has a preceding limit ordinal (counting zero as a limit ordinal).

I am not sure if this is true but if it is $\bigcup\{\delta\mid\delta < \gamma \text{ and } \delta \text{ is a limit ordinal} \} $ would be the candidate.

I can prove a union of limit ordinals is a limit ordinal. It's proving the above limit ordinal is less than $\gamma$ that is unclear to me.

Comment: Limit ordinals **never** have (immediate) predecessors, that's what makes them limit ordinals.

Comment: Sorry, will fix my question, I meant preceding limit ordinal.

Comment: This version is also false: consider a limit of limit ordinals, such as $\omega^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement you are trying to prove is **not true**. If $\lambda$ is a (nonzero) **limit of limit ordinals**, then - by definition - there is no greatest limit ordinal $<\lambda$.

The first limit-of-limits is $\omega^2$: we have $\omega^2=\sup\{\omega,\omega\cdot 2,\omega\cdot 3,...\}$ and clearly each $\omega\cdot n$ is a limit ordinal. Similarly, there are ordinals which are limits-of-limits-of-limits such as $\omega^3=\sup\{\omega^2,\omega^2\cdot 2,\omega^2\cdot 3,...\}$ - or $\omega^\omega$, or [$\epsilon_0$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epsilon_numbers_(mathematics)), or [$\omega_1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_uncountable_ordinal), or etc.

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The very first limit ordinal is $\omega$,  it's the ordinal that's the union of all the natural numbers.  It clearly has no immediate predecessor. As per the comment, that's what makes these limit ordinals.

Comment: This *was* the correct answer to the question as originally posed, but then the question was edited.

Comment: Thanks Alan, I feel if you read my candidate answer you would have inferred what my actual question was. I was not using the word predecessor in its technical sense, I was using it in the context of limit ordinal.